# spark sql- select record having least difference in 2 date columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is the logic in SQL:

```
coalesce(if effc_dt <= tran_dt select(max of effc_dt) , if effc_dt >= tran_dt select (min of effc_dt)).
```

I want similar logic in Pyspark, when effc date is lesser than tran date it will select effc date closest to tran date and if lesser date is not present it will check for greater and select effc date closest to tran date.

**Input dataframe:**

```
|id|tran_date  |effc_date  |
|--|-----------|-----------|
|12|2020-02-01 |2019-02-01 |
|12|2020-02-01 |2018-02-01 |
|34|2020-02-01 |2021-02-15 |
|34|2020-02-01 |2020-02-15 |
|40|2020-02-01 |2019-02-15 |
|40|2020-02-01 |2020-03-15 |
```

**Expected Output:**

```
|id|tran_date  |effc_date  |
|--|-----------|-----------|
|12|2020-02-01 |2019-02-01 |
|34|2020-02-01 |2020-02-15 |
|40|2020-02-01 |2019-02-15 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order by the date difference and limit the results to 1 row:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'rn', 
    F.row_number().over(
        Window.partitionBy('ID')
              .orderBy(F.datediff('start_date', 'end_date'))
    )
).filter('rn = 1').drop('rn')

df2.show()
+---+----------+----------+
| id|start_date|  end_date|
+---+----------+----------+
| 34|2021-02-01|2019-02-01|
| 12|2020-02-01|2019-02-01|
+---+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks @mck for your answer! 
There are many rows, I have updated the question, could you please have a look?

Comment: I have ticked green.. Thanks! However I have added more specific details to question, if you can help that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @AbhishekMishra please avoid modifying questions after they have been answered. Instead, please open another question. thanks

Comment: Noted, I am a newbie at stackoverflow. Could you please have a look at revised question? Thanks in advance!